# React context official plans

Tags: reactjs

Does anyone haved insight into or know how to find out the official plans and/or direction reagarding React `context`? It's been well over a year of experimental use at your own risk status that wasn't even initially documented.

Without a full flux implementation (which may be overkill for some things) there really isn't a viable alternative for what context provides, so it would be nice to get some type of closure here! Some of us would sleep better at night knowing we wouldn't have to explain why we used experimental code to our bosses if the stuff hit the fan...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same concern when first reading the docs.

But having looked through the react internals searching for `context` related code. I found plenty of test cases and a relatively uncomplicated api for the `context` feature.

Seems to me **the experimental label is more to avoid/deter the bypassing of the props and state react primarily focuses itself around**.

But don't take just my word, look at how `context` is used in react-redux and react-router.... I don't think will be fundamentally changing anytime soon.